# OpenGL ES 2: 2D water effect

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've just started working with OpenGL 2.0 on Android a few days ago.
I've figured out how to draw simple 2D rectagles, triangles, lines, adding textures etc.
But I'm trying to create a 2D water effect using the accelerometer of my device.
I'm able to get the right values of the accelerometer to my Renderer but that's not the issue.

I want the create something like the iBeer app. It's a drink with foam on top. So how can I make sure the edge where the drink touches the foam acts like the water effect, with small 'waves'. Do I need a certain vertex or fragment shader?

Comment: well, that's the problem, I don't really have a starting point. I don't know how to change the shape of an element at runtime

Comment: Did you try simply searching for "how to make an app like ibeer" and then read some of the results? It gives me some good results and ideas of how to make it.

Comment: yep, did that search, but I didn't find a any good examples

Comment: There are excellent examples of water effects in OpenGL ES in the PowerVR SDK, which is a free download. http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdkdownloads/index.asp